# parRapply whats wrong?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, apply

I have a list of e-mails and I would like to compare patterns (similarity) among the rows using longest common substring to compare them.

data is a data frame with 300.000 e-mails:

```
         V1
1   "01003@163.com"
2   "cloud@coldmail.com"
3   "den_smukk_kiilar@hotmail.com"
4   "Esteban.verduzco@gmail.com"
5   "freiheitmensch@gmail.com"
6   "mitsoanastos@yahoo.com"
7   "ahmedsir744@yahoo.com" 
8   ...
```

I am using this code:

```
# Compare Strings Difference
compare_strings = function(j,i) {
  value = as.numeric(stringdist(data[j,],data[i,],method='lcs', nthread = 2))   
  pair <- rbind(data[j,], data[i,],value)
  return(pair)
}

i = 0 
kk = 1 

while(kk<nrow(data)) {

  i = i+1 # fix row
  j = c((kk+1):nrow(data)) # rows to be compared 

  # Apply Function "compare_strings" for row "i" with all the others rows  
  out <- as.matrix(t(apply(expand.grid(i,j),1, function(x,y)  compare_strings(x[1],x[2]))))

  kk = kk +1
}
```

That works perfectly! But I have 300.000 e-mail, and I am trying to parallelize the process buy doing:

```
require(parallel)

 clus <- makeCluster(2)

 clusterEvalQ(clus,  compare.strings <- function(j,i) {
    library(stringdist)
    value = as.numeric(stringdist(data[j,],data[i,],method='lcs', nthread = 2))
    pair <- rbind(data[j,], data[i,],value)
    return(pair)
  })

  out = as.matriz(t(parRapply(clus, expand.grid(i,j),function(x,y) compare.strings(x[1],x[2]))))
```

But I get:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

What Am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to compare the amount of strings?

Answer (score 1):

We need to export the data using "clusterExport".

```
#Create cluster

clus <- makeCluster(8)

clusterExport(clus, list("data","stringdist") , envir=environment())

clusterEvalQ(clus,
             compare_strings <- function(j,i) {
               #library(stringdist)
               #print(i)
               value = as.numeric(stringdist(data[j,],data[i,],method='lcs', nthread = 8))
               pair <- rbind(data[j,],data[i,],value)
               return(pair) 
             })
```

and define i and j range, we can run:

```
#Apply the declared function  

out = matrix(unlist(parRapply(clus,expand.grid(i,j), function(x,y) compare_strings(x[1],x[2]))),ncol=3, byrow = T)
```